# Unable to access element of iframe with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have literally tried everything I could think of so far and searched everywhere but haven't been able to find a working solution.

I am trying to automate the process of creating Advertisement Links on a website called Linkvertise. My current code is:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options



chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=selenium") 

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

link_to_publish = "https://random.com/2937"

browser.get("https://publisher.linkvertise.com/dashboard#link-create")

# set link
browser.switch_to.frame("link-create-iframe") 
browser.find_element(By.ID, "mat-input-0").send_keys(link_to_publish)

# click continue
sleep(3)
browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body > app-root > lv-link-create-page-component > div > lv-lm-page > div > div.col.p-0 > div > lv-lm-button-wrapper > div > lv-button.mat-tooltip-trigger > a").click()

# toggle off visibility
sleep(3)
browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#mat-slide-toggle-2 > label > div").click()

# set title
sleep(3)
browser.find_element(By.ID, 'mat-input-8')
```

You need to run it once and login manually, it will then store the session in the current directory and you can start running the full program.

I still have the sleep times in there as I wanted the process to be a little slower.

**My issue:**
The element is on the second page of the iframe (image attached). I have already successfully access other elements within that iframe, even on the same page. But for some reason I am not able to add the link description (bottom of my screenshot).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lUiZ.png)

Does anyone know why that is?

I will also provide some dummy login details if anyone is willing to check, I would highly appreciate it!!

Email: pschw1@tellofon.com
Password: Pschw123!

**HTML Code of the element** I'm trying to access:

```
<input lvpreventdoublespacesdoublenewlines="" autocomplete="off" formcontrolname="btn_text" matinput="" spellcheck="false" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-touched ng-pristine ng-invalid cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored highlight-textarea" maxlength="50" placeholder="Beschreibe deinen Link präzise in wenigen Worten" required="" id="mat-input-22" data-placeholder="Beschreibe deinen Link präzise in wenigen Worten" aria-required="true">
```

What I tried so far:

- using higher sleep delays incase the error just came from the content not loading in time
- leaving the iframe incase the element wasn't actually inside it
- finding element by ID, class name, css selector, xpath

I've searched for help in other online forums and even looked for help on fiverr, but nobody was able to provide a solution yet.

Comment: do you get an error or something?

Comment: @soundwave yes a “there’s no such element” exception

Answer (score 0):

This element's ID `mat-input-8` is a dynamic one, it is keep on changing everytime, you can use the below one:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".input-area.single-line-input input").send_keys("something for testing")
```